# How to read tab delimited lines by skipping alternate lines

Tags: c#, asp.net, split, skip, csv

I am currently able to parse and extract data from large tab delimited file. I am reading, parsing and extracting line by line and adding the split items in my Data table (Row Limit adding 3 rows at a time). I need to skip even lines i.e. Read first maximum tab delimited line and then skip 2nd one and read the third one directly.

My Tab delimited source file format

```
001Mean                   26.975                  1.1403                  910.45                   
001Stdev                  26.975                  1.1403                  910.45                   
002Mean                   26.975                  1.1403                  910.45                   
002Stdev                  26.975                  1.1403                  910.45
```

Need to skip or avoid reading Stdev tab delimited lines.

C# Code:

Getting the Maximum length of items in a tab delimited line of the file by splitting a line

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
        {
            string line = null;
            line = reader.ReadToEnd();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                var list_with_max_cols = line.Split('\n').OrderByDescending(y => y.Split('\t').Count()).Take(1);
                foreach (var value in list_with_max_cols)
                {
                   var values = value.ToString().Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
                   MAX_NO_OF_COLUMNS = values.Length;
                }
            }
        }
```

Reading the file line by line until maximum length in a tab delimited line is satisfied as first line to parse and extract

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
        {
            string new_read_line = null;
            //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.                
            while ((new_read_line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                            var items = new_read_line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
                            if (items.Length != MAX_NO_OF_COLUMNS)                         
                            continue;
                //when reach first line it is column list need to create datatable based on that.
                if (firstLineOfFile)
                {

                    columnData = new_read_line;
                    firstLineOfFile = false;
                    continue;
                }
                if (firstLineOfChunk)
                {
                    firstLineOfChunk = false;
                    chunkDataTable = CreateEmptyDataTable(columnData);
                }
                    AddRow(chunkDataTable, new_read_line);
                chunkRowCount++;

                if (chunkRowCount == _chunkRowLimit)
                {
                    firstLineOfChunk = true;
                    chunkRowCount = 0;
                    yield return chunkDataTable;
                    chunkDataTable = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Creating Data Table:

```
private DataTable CreateEmptyDataTable(string firstLine)
    {

        IList<string> columnList = Split(firstLine);
        var dataTable = new DataTable("TableName");
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnList.Count; columnIndex++)
        {
            string c_string = columnList[columnIndex];
            if (Regex.Match(c_string, "\\s").Success)
            {
                string tmp = Regex.Replace(c_string, "\\s", "");
                string finaltmp = Regex.Replace(tmp, @" ?\[.*?\]", ""); // To strip strings inside [] and inclusive [] alone
                columnList[columnIndex] = finaltmp;

            }
        }
        dataTable.Columns.AddRange(columnList.Select(v => new DataColumn(v)).ToArray());
        dataTable.Columns.Add("ID");
        return dataTable;

    }

How to skip lines by reading alternatively and split and then add to my datatable !!!
```

AddRow Function : Managed to achieve my requirement by adding following changes !!!

```
private void AddRow(DataTable dataTable, string line)
    {

        if (line.Contains("Stdev"))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
          //Rest of Code
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have tab separated values in each line, how about reading the odd lines and splitting them into arrays. This is just a sample; you can expand upon this.

Test data (file.txt)

```
luck    is  when    opportunity meets   preparation
this    line    needs   to  be  skipped
microsoft   visual  studio
another line    to  be  skipped
let us  all code
```

Code

```
var oddLines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\projects\file.txt").Where((item, index) => index%2 == 0);
foreach (var line in oddLines)
{
     var words = line.Split('\t');
}
```

Debug screen shots

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

**EDIT**

To get lines that don't contain 'Stdev'

```
var filteredLines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\projects\file.txt").Where(item => !item.Contains("Stdev"));
```

Comment: @ Prashanth Thanks for your comments!!! I have added changes to my code. I realized late that, using the index % 2 == 0 may not fit in my requirement as the stdev line might be existing in both odd and even index of tab delimited lines in my source file.

Comment: @Shrivatsan My answer was based on your original requirements. Anyway good to know you found your fix. Still you could modify my query to filter only the data you wanted. See my edited query.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
    {
        string new_read_line = null;
        //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.                
        while ((new_read_line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
                        var items = new_read_line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
                        if (items.Length != MAX_NO_OF_COLUMNS)                         
                        continue;
```

To

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(sourceFileFullName))
    {

        int cnt = 0;
        string new_read_line = null;
        //Read and display lines from the file until the end of the file is reached.                
        while ((new_read_line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
                        cnt++;

                        if(cnt % 2 == 0)
                           continue;
                        var items = new_read_line.Split(new[] { '\t', '\n' }).ToArray();
                        if (items.Length != MAX_NO_OF_COLUMNS)                         
                        continue;
```

Comment: @ Gusman Thanks for your comments!!! I have added changes to my code. I realized late that, using the cnt % 2 == 0 may not fit in my requirement as the stdev line might be existing in both odd and even index of tab delimited lines in my source file.